# Dense Rank grouping by IDs

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having trouble getting my DENSE_RANK() function in Oracle to work how I would like. First, my dataset:

```
ID      DATE
1234    01-OCT-2020
1234    01-OCT-2021
1234    01-OCT-2022
2345    01-APR-2020
2345    01-APR-2021
2345    01-APR-2022
```

I am trying to use the dense rank function to return results with a sequence number based on the DATE field, and grouping by ID. How I want the data to return:

```
ID      DATE           SEQ
1234    01-OCT-2020    1
1234    01-OCT-2021    2
1234    01-OCT-2022    3
2345    01-APR-2020    1
2345    01-APR-2021    2
2345    01-APR-2022    3
```

The query I have so far:

```
 SELECT ID, DATE, DENSE_RANK() Over (order by ID, DATE asc) as SEQ
```

However, this returns incorrectly as the sequence number will go to 6 (Like its disregarding my intentions to sequence based on the DATE field within a certain ID). If anyone has any insights into how to make this work it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `row_number()`:

```
select id, date, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seq
```

You could actually use `dense_rank()` as well, if you want duplicates to have the same idea.  The key idea is `partition by`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This was exactly my issue! I will mark it as Solved as soon as the timer lets me!

Comment: In addition, here's a Microsoft documentation link explaining/comparing ranking functions: 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you! partition by was what I needed badly here thank you